# How to make the best use of the ring of life

Tags: magic

So basically the only magic in the world comes from artifacts that fall from the sky on a more or less weekly basis that clearly have some sort of creator but no one can say exactly who or what that may be. The protagonist who makes a living finding and selling artifacts has decided to keep his latest find for himself due to it being a possible way for him to avoid dying, him being obsessed with immortality or otherwise remaining alive to a fault. Currently he only knows that the ring heals the wounds of whatever it touches, with him finding out more about it as the story goes on. He's not a very selfish person but this may eventually develop into a 'my precious' situation. Artifacts seem to ignore all laws of physics as they do what they do, and if they do abide by them in some way it's not certain how. The technology level of most of the world is 13th century central Europe, with one or two very powerful artifacts making life a little easier for everyone like increasing plant growth rate and ensuring fertile soil in a wide area(better crops) and a material separator(currently used to more cleanly separate mined materials from rock, leading to pure iron and such).

Artifact summary:

**Ring of Life**

A seemingly silver ring engraved with depictions of animals and humanoids in various states of health, from skeletal and dead to full of life in prime fitness. Its head holds an oval red gem that has within its core a faint red light that pulses like a heartbeat and is warm to the touch.

Artifact properties:

1. Regenerates flesh and bone at a 1 cubic centimeter per minute rate of whatever is in physical contact with the ring. This permits both the wearer and those who touch the ring to benefit from the power of the ring. There is no limit to how many may benefit from the regeneration aside from how many living things can touch the ring at the same time. The ring only regenerates things that are damaged, preventing overgrowth or malign growths from its influence. If given enough time it will also regrow organs and limbs/whole sections of the body.
2. If something is clinically dead or brain dead that the ring is in contact with it will restart the heart and give rise to brain activity as soon as it has regenerated the associated organs to a state where they can continue functioning on their own once it has made them active once more. There needs to still be some living tissues in the body for this to work, so a body of completely dead cells or a skeletal body will not be resurrected but a recently killed or dead thing may be resurrected. If an organism needs oxygen or some other resource to function post-resurrection it will make the lungs breathe, refill it with blood, or whatever is necessary for the resurrection to succeed.
3. If there is a substance in a organism that is harmful to its survival like a poison then it will try to force the body to expel it but if unsuccessful will turn it into water or whatever would be the least harmful wherever the substance is in the body.
4. If an organism in contact with the ring is suffering something in it that will eventually kill it but is from a living source like cancer, diseases, or a parasite then it will not deal with it, for they are alive and it does nothing negative to living things. It will still try to make the organism functional despite these things, and so the organism may suffer until these sources are eventually dealt with externally by medical means or by the body's own mechanisms. The ring recognizes removal of harmful tissues as a way to keep something alive, and so will not regenerate things like cancer cells.
5. Any organism that is in contact with the ring will have its life extended in some way, for example in humans it's the lengthening of telomeres and otherwise revitalizing the body with things like higher collagen, etc. This does lead to loss of senescence but if something continually damages the body(like radiation or otherwise) and the ring has to compensate then the organism may eventually die despite the ring's efforts anyway.
6. The ring does not prevent things from being killed from external factors like being run through with a sword, etc, but as per point 2 if it remains in contact with the killed thing it will eventually resurrect, something the protagonist will eventually find out as it is planned that he gets killed at some point.
7. Infected or otherwise dying bio-matter is regarded as non-recoverable damaged material and will have the underlying flesh be prioritized for regeneration until the body sheds the material.
8. The ring does keep you alive as far as hunger and thirst goes, but it will not keep your body healthily fed or properly hydrated, so you may very well end up persisting emaciated and dehydrated if you don't look after yourself. As far as sustenance goes the ring's only concern is that you remain alive.

**For as long as he remains unselfish, what would be the best way to make use of this ring?**

Protagonist extra information.

27 years of age, he is an orphan who has found a way out of the usual fate of orphans in the alleys through the finding and selling of artifacts that have landed in the wilds. His occupation is inherently hazardous with artifact hunters being competitively cutthroat in the retrieval of artifacts, their approximate location being marked by what seems like a falling star, and so he has some experience in dagger/sword combat but for the most part he trains to be fast and agile. His financial situation is not very dire due to him being a rather proficient hunter but with more artifact hunters joining the scene every year he runs the risk of being out-competed and so must find a different source of income to fall back on if his current profession falls through the floorboards. This is arguably one of the more powerful artifacts, so naturally there comes some form of greed and envy over it, which he has to deal with throughout the story.

Comment: This looks very like a story-based question which will result in opinion-based answers, two reasons it's likely to get closed.  The primary reason for it being opinion-based is that we have no way of knowing what the protagonist thinks is "best".  Is his priority keeping his family alive, or continuously resurrecting the cow that gave him the best steaks he's ever eaten?  Or something completely different?  "Unselfish" means different things to different people.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 for God's sake every question in WorldBuilding is opinion-based for the very reason they are about fictonal worlds. If a world doesn't exist, every and all answers regarding it are by definition opinion-based. Just ask questions to clarify OP's question and help him improve it.

Comment: @Lemming your property #8 is a bit controversial. A body lacking proper nutrition / hydration will suffer damage on its cells until death comes. If the ring acts to reapair that damage in real time, the body will survive healthly forever, even without being fed.

Comment: @CharleyR. True I suppose, but I did not want someone to be in their prime condition simply for being in possession of the ring. If they want to be anything more than a scrawny weakling they'd need to look after and improve themselves is what I was trying to convey, then again with how muscle building works(damage+repair) I suppose this might not work out like I envisioned point 8.

Comment: @CharleyR. while it's true that most questions can't be answered with certainty, this one has no criteria provided for judging what a good answer will be, as "best" depends on the beliefs, intelligence and priorities of a single character about whom we know nothing other than occupation.  "Keep the Pope alive at all costs"; "Preserve my immediate family"; or "Maintain the health of the best horses in the village" could be the "best" answer for the protagonist but we have no way of guessing which are good suggestions and which are not.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Fair enough. Then the answer would pure opinion-based, instead of just opinion-based. All answers here are opinion-based, but they should also rely on some criteria to be formulated and accepted. OP should provide some goal of the main character to help us judge what "best use" means, as the best use would be the one helping the character to achieve his objectives more efficiently.

Comment: @CharleyR. If you're asking about an individual planning to accomplish a goal then you're not asking a question about building a world you're asking a question about a story set in a world, which is also off topic.

Comment: @sphennings Absolutely not. "If the character's goal is to become rich, what is the best use of a healing artifact?" I have a hard time picturing this question as off-topic. If it is, I can name a lot of other questions in this website that should be closed too. In fact, most of them.

Comment: @CharleyR. How is that a question about building a fictional world? To quote from the help center "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story." The rules of the world have been established. What's left is to determine a specific characters actions within it. We have a specific close reason just for questions that are too story based.

Comment: @sphennings A possible answer to that question would be "Use it to create a great hospital". Does it sound like "telling the story" to you? Since such a healing item doesn't exist, it is natural that such question on how to use it effectively arises. A story that uses the ideas presented in the answer is many levels deeper than the answer itself.

Comment: @CharleyR. We're here to help people establish the rules of their world, we're not here to answer "Given my **fully built world** what will my character do in it?" If you'd like to get a better understanding of site policy I suggest you ask your questions on meta instead of arguing in someone else's comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice find ! Have a well paid job serving nobility,

**Personal physician**

In the 13th century in Europe, this person would be in service of the king, or queen, or count, or bishop, making sure they are cured of any disease.. and their spouse and family too.. They got [famous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthias_de_l%27Obel) and rich.. In GB they even invented a title for it [Physician to the Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physician_to_the_Queen)

These court physicians became nobility themselves, in the 15th-17th century they founded botanical gardens and greenhouses for research and medicin. This man would be a VERY good physician though.. he could become the center of court intrige, when they find out he can cure  people of (really) any wound, or disease.

Being able to cure the wounds of a king, or high nobility during battle would  have been a fantastic strategic asset in war, in the 13th century.

**How to keep the ring ?**

I can't fill in your story, but probably, he will *loose* the ring at some point. Find a way to let him get it back, hide it.. find it back, keep it.. thing is, if it works in the hands of others too.. they won't need him. Maybe in a court (of any kind) he should keep the ring's working secret, or demand that the patient vows not to reveal his methods. Maybe he can invent certain rituals, where the working of the ring will not be noticed.

Answer (score 4):

**You know how.**

You tip your hand in the OP here:
/with one or two very powerful artifacts making life a little easier for everyone/

This ring is the newest one of those.  All the frufru about how it works is windowdressing.  The story is the human story.  This guy would set himself up to heal people who came to him.  He could make trips to other cities to heal people too sick to come to where he was.  Persons would accompany him on these trips to keep him safe and share the glory.  Grateful persons would give huge gifts.  It would be a sweet gig and everyone wins.

But if that happens it wont happen for long because you tipped your hand again. /For as long as he remains unselfish/

Something will happen.  Maybe one of the very powerful aforementioned artifacts gets stolen and its keepers slaughtered.  Or it runs out of juice.  Your guy is worried about the ring and his own safety and so he does not keep doing the good thing he started doing.

---

The trick for your story is not these things because you have already thought of them.  The trick is how he redeems himself or comes to peace with the state of things by the end of the story.

Comment: I was writing a post to simply say "go into the miracle healing business", but you got me beat. :D

Comment: the "something" that will happen is clearly that the wearer will get killed and the ring taken, within days. everybody who can hold a sword (or buy someone who can) will want to have a powerful artefact like this.

Comment: @ths - that scene would be exciting. It is not so easy to kill someone wearing this ring.

Comment: see point 6. killing is easy, and if you lop off the finger with the ring, resurrection won't occur anytime soon either...